# Android App crashes only with release APK

Tags: android, apk

I have a curious issue. I built an app that works fine in debug mode (direkt debugging to my phone and with debug APK installed on my phone) but the app crashes at one point if I use the release build APK.
I found the point where the app crashes with release APK, but I don't know why and what I can do:

```
protected final String TABLE = "done";
protected final String COL_ID = "_id";
protected final String COL_TASK = "taskid";
protected final String COL_DATE = "donedate";

protected String getLastDoneDate(String id) {
    String date = "";

    String filter = COL_TASK + " LIKE ?";
    String[] filterArgs = new String[] {id};
    String sortOrder = COL_DATE + " DESC";
    String[] columns = new String[] {COL_DATE};
    Cursor c = MyTime.db.query(TABLE, columns, filter, filterArgs, null, null, sortOrder, "1");
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_DATE));
    }
    c.close();

    return date;
}
```

If I remove the line Cursor c = ... (and all according to c) it works.

Database looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS done (
                _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
                taskid INTEGER,
                donedate TEXT DEFAULT '');
```

Gradle Snippet:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I can not debug to find the problem because the crash does'nt happen while debugging.

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: try to update db version

Comment: Try to reinstall de app in the cellphone

Comment: I tried changing db-Version and I deinstalled the app before installing it again

Comment: post the logcat with the crash. Use debuggable true in release

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow

Comment: if it works on debug but not on release, then it is usually an issue with proguard. you might want to post your gradle file and your proguard file.

Comment: With flag debuggable I found out that my sql-create-table statement was wrong. I tried to create 2 tables at a time (db.execSQL = "CREATE TABLE a; CREATE TABLE b;").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I added debuggable = true to my gradle file and found the reason of my problem.

```
buildTypes {
release {
    shrinkResources false
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
debug {
    shrinkResources false
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
```

Table "done" was not created because I tried to put two table create statements into a single db.execSQL()

Comment: Note that if you are working in Android Studio you have to click "Debug 'App'" instead of "Run 'App'" after changing your gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the SQLite, you can check proguard-rules.pro file, it maybe makes release.apk crash. if you want to lean more, click https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: The issue does also appear if I set shrink to false

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes only if you add the below line in release section of build.gradle file:

```
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

> Use this instead of above:

```
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Sample of gradle file looks like this and it resolved my issue:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you! Happy coding...

Comment: For me it had to do ProGuard obfuscating some of my classes. Anyone having issues related release builds crashing debuggable and use that to trace what ProGuard is doing. Once you know where the crash is coming from (after enable debug mode in release), you can use the mapping.txt file to trace the line crashing the crash

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue I also found and mentioned about it in https://medium.com/@aanshul16/android-app-crashes-in-release-mode-but-working-perfectly-in-debug-c051cc83a019 
So you can check first by enabling "minifyEnable" to true in your debug flavour if issue get reproduced in debug mode also then definitely it is because of proguard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it by making both minifyEnabled and shrinkResources false

```
 release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```